# Touchpad not working on Fujitsu UH552 after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad

I have added "i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX= in /etc/default/grub as a hack to get the touchpad to work on my Fujitsu Lifebook uh552, but it stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.
I tried to update grub, but it didn't help.
Here is my dmesg output for synaptics:

```
dmesg | grep -i synaptics  
[    1.948529] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5472], y [..4448]
[    2.005337] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.0, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x120c00/0x0, board id: 1722, fw id: 799475
[    2.041550] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[  364.144452] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5472], y [..4448]
[  364.201891] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.0, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x120c00/0x0, board id: 1722, fw id: 799475
[  364.240948] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input124
```

My Ubuntu has already been upgraded once before and I had no issues with the 15.04 upgrade.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have this similar problem. But it happened after I did a recent update for my 14.04. Did some search on internet and found this fix, may be you can try.
Go to TERMINAL and type this command:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo reboot
```

this fix is taken from the forum (more similar to you case): [Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322413)